# How to use ReactiveUI with MvvmCross

Tags: xamarin, mvvmcross, reactiveui

I would like to use parts of ReactiveUI in an MvvmCross application. I am not using Xamarin.Forms.

I have managed to create a ViewModel based on ReactiveObject. While it does seem to work, I'm worried there might be ramifications in MvvmCross that I do not understand.

```
public abstract class ReactiveMvxViewModel : ReactiveObject, IMvxViewModel
    {
        protected ReactiveMvxViewModel()
        {

        }
        
        public virtual void ViewCreated()
        {
        }

        public virtual void ViewAppearing()
        {
        }

        public virtual void ViewAppeared()
        {
        }

        public virtual void ViewDisappearing()
        {
        }

        public virtual void ViewDisappeared()
        {
        }

        public virtual void ViewDestroy(bool viewFinishing = true)
        {
        }

        public void Init(IMvxBundle parameters)
        {
            InitFromBundle(parameters);
        }

        public void ReloadState(IMvxBundle state)
        {
            ReloadFromBundle(state);
        }

        public virtual void Start()
        {
        }

        public void SaveState(IMvxBundle state)
        {
            SaveStateToBundle(state);
        }

        protected virtual void InitFromBundle(IMvxBundle parameters)
        {
        }

        protected virtual void ReloadFromBundle(IMvxBundle state)
        {
        }

        protected virtual void SaveStateToBundle(IMvxBundle bundle)
        {
        }

        public virtual void Prepare()
        {
        }

        public virtual Task Initialize()
        {
            return Task.FromResult(true);
        }

        private MvxNotifyTask _initializeTask;
        public MvxNotifyTask InitializeTask
        {
            get => _initializeTask;
            set => this.RaiseAndSetIfChanged(ref _initializeTask, value);
        }

        public ViewModelActivator Activator { get; }
    }
    
    public abstract class ReactiveMvxViewModel<TParameter> : ReactiveMvxViewModel, IMvxViewModel<TParameter>
        where TParameter : notnull
    {
        public abstract void Prepare(TParameter parameter);
    }

    //TODO: Not possible to name MvxViewModel, name is MvxViewModelResult for now
    public abstract class ReactiveMvxViewModelResult<TResult> : ReactiveMvxViewModel, IMvxViewModelResult<TResult>
        where TResult : notnull
    {
        public TaskCompletionSource<object> CloseCompletionSource { get; set; }

        public override void ViewDestroy(bool viewFinishing = true)
        {
            if (viewFinishing && CloseCompletionSource != null && !CloseCompletionSource.Task.IsCompleted && !CloseCompletionSource.Task.IsFaulted)
                CloseCompletionSource?.TrySetCanceled();

            base.ViewDestroy(viewFinishing);
        }
    }

    public abstract class ReactiveMvxViewModel<TParameter, TResult> : ReactiveMvxViewModelResult<TResult>, IMvxViewModel<TParameter, TResult>
        where TParameter : notnull
        where TResult : notnull
    {
        public abstract void Prepare(TParameter parameter);
    }
```

This seems to work. I am able to use a MvxViewController and bind to the properties using MvvmCross's method of binding.

But since the viewmodel is no longer a MvxViewModel I can't use SetProperty. Which is probably fine, but are there any other problems I would run into with the approach down the line?

I like MvvmCross and how it handles navigation, dependency injection, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Worth checking out the [Interoperability with ReactiveUI](https://rodneylittlesii.com/posts/topic/reactiveui-interop) article by Rodney Littles II. This article is so so good at explaining how ReactiveUI works and how to combine ReactiveUI with other MVVM frameworks. There is also a [ReactiveUI.Interop](https://github.com/RocketSurgeonsGuild/ReactiveUI.Interop) repository that contains code examples, including interoperability examples with `FreshMvvm`, `Prism`, and `MvvmCross`. See also [ReactiveUI.Interop/src](https://github.com/RocketSurgeonsGuild/ReactiveUI.Interop/tree/master/src). There is a `SetProperty<T>` method available (see [MvxReactiveViewModel.cs](https://github.com/RocketSurgeonsGuild/ReactiveUI.Interop/blob/master/src/ReactiveUI.Interop.MvvmCross/MvxReactiveViewModel.cs)).

Comment: I really thought that would be the answer. But upon trying it, it doesn't seem like I am able to use ObservableAsPropertyHelper.

In fact, Rodney himself has said it doesn't look like it works with the IReactiveObject interface alone. https://reactivex.slack.com/archives/C02AJB872/p1606936693377300?thread_ts=1606923358.377000&cid=C02AJB872

Comment: Yeah then probably worth switching from `SetProperty` over to `RaiseAndSetIfChanged` or implementing `SetProperty` in your `ReactiveMvxViewModel` like this I guess https://github.com/RocketSurgeonsGuild/ReactiveUI.Interop/blob/master/src/ReactiveUI.Interop.MvvmCross/MvxReactiveViewModel.cs#L64 But yeah might be worth waiting for other answers from those who use MvvmCross with ReactiveUI.

Comment: I'm guessing we're both more familiar with MvvmCross than ReactiveUI. Any idea what I would lose by just using IMvxViewModel?